# C++. gtk_window_resize doesn't resize window

Tags: c++, gtk, gnome

I've got class (called `BorderWindow`) which is in fact wrap around `GtkWidget`. This class represents border around specific application's window (lets say Terminal window, for instance). Inside of `BorderWindow` constructor I create timer so every second `BorderWindow::ClockTick` function is called.
Inside of this function border size (which is actually `GtkWidget`) is compared with bound application's window (Terminal in our case) and if it differs `gtk_window_resize` is called. However, if I call then `gtk_window_get_size` it returns old values.

```
gboolean BorderWindow::ClockTick(gpointer data)
{
auto that = reinterpret_cast<BorderWindow*>(data);

int x = 0, y = 0;
GtkWindow* pWindow = GTK_WINDOW(that->m_borderWindowHandle);
gtk_window_get_size(pWindow, &x, &y);
DUMPER_INFO("curr size: %dx%d; new size: %dx%d", x, y, that->m_windowRect.width, that->m_windowRect.height); // added for debug
if(x != that->m_windowRect.width || y != that->m_windowRect.height)
{
    gtk_window_resize(pWindow, that->m_windowRect.width, that->m_windowRect.height);
    that->CreateBorder();
    GtkWindow* pWindow = GTK_WINDOW(that->m_borderWindowHandle); // added for debug
    gtk_window_get_size(pWindow, &x, &y); // added for debug
    DUMPER_INFO("after resize: %dx%d", x, y); // added for debug
}

gtk_window_get_position(pWindow, &x, &y);
if(x != that->m_windowRect.x || y != that->m_windowRect.y)
{
    gtk_window_move(pWindow, that->m_windowRect.x, that->m_windowRect.y);
}
gdk_window_invalidate_rect(gtk_widget_get_window(that->m_borderWindowHandle), nullptr, FALSE);
that->m_highlightFrame = !that->m_highlightFrame;

return TRUE;
}
```

Here is debug output

> 20-05-19 11:24:40.294 [139856177248000] INFO  1537 %% - static gboolean LinuxBorderWindow::ClockTick(gpointer): curr size: 734x540; new size: 1024x706
>
> 20-05-19 11:24:40.295 [139856177248000] INFO  1537 %% - static gboolean LinuxBorderWindow::ClockTick(gpointer): after resize: 734x540

So as you can see, the window wasn't resized.
This code snippet works fine for xfce and Unity DEs, but doesn't work for GNOME (and GNOME classic).
Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to resize window for GNOME DE?
Thanks.